# Error while deploying on google app engine java spring mvc maven plugin 1.9.18 NoSuchElementException

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-app-engine, maven-plugin, gwt-maven-plugin

```
        <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>gmultipart</id>
        <url>http://gmultipart.googlecode.com/svn/repo/m2</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>


    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <groupId>com.example.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.2.5</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Dependencies..See end for spring.version 4.0.6.RELEASE -->
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <groupId>gmultipart</groupId>
        <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.18</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                            <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                    <webResources>
                        <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.15</version>
            <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to bind to all IPs instead of just localhost -->
                    <!-- address>0.0.0.0</address>
                    <port>8080</port -->
                    <!-- Comment in the below snippet to enable local debugging with a remove debugger
                         like those included with Eclipse or IntelliJ -->
                    <!-- jvmFlags>
                      <jvmFlag>-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n</jvmFlag>
                    </jvmFlags -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </pluginManagement>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application-->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
           </build>

</project>
```

My pom.xml.  I am trying to deploy this on google app engine but getting the below error.  What am I doing wrong?

I am using Spring MVC and google-app-sdk 1.9.18.  Below is the error:

```
Retrieving Google App Engine Java SDK from Maven
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.574 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-17T21:24:17-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/185M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update (default-cli) on project example: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.18:update failed. NoSuchElementException -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: You have no `<project>` opening tag in your XML, I don't think that file is even valid XML that way.

Comment: yeah I kind of edited those parts..I think the issue is somewhere in this plugin     <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.18</version>  I tried different versions no luck.